# Adding a link to a Button in Flash/Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, button

How do I make a link on a button which is in a Flash movie clip?

Comment: please specify your question.. what AS version? What have you tried?

Comment: hello sir.

i am working on flash menu. in this menu i make a 4 tabs.. in each tabs i have 2 text.. in this text i have to give a link on google.com. and i also have to add a underline when my mouse over the text.

i m useing a adobe flash cs3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your button has an instance name of "myButton", on the frame where your button is in the timeline, you'll add the following (or similar) Actionscript.

**AS2**

```
myButton.onPress = function()
{
   getURL("http://stackoverflow.com", "_blank");
}
```

**AS3**

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);
function onMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com");
   request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
   var target:String = "_blank";
   navigateToURL(request, target);
}
```

**Backwards compatible getURL for AS3**

```
/**
 * Backwards compatibility for global getURL function.
 *
 * @param url     Url to go to.
 * @param method  'get' or 'post'.
 * @param target  Window target frame [ex. '_blank'].
 */
public static function getURL(url:String, target:String = '_blank', method:String = 'get'):void
{
    method = method.toUpperCase();
    target = target.toLowerCase();

    if (method != URLRequestMethod.POST && method != URLRequestMethod.GET) method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    if (target != "_self" && target != "_blank" && target != "_parent" && target != "_top") target = "_blank";
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    request.method = method;
    navigateToURL(request, target);
}
```

Note that in both AS2 and AS3 you could write this code in a class and set the class as the export class for your button/movieclip. This is probably a bit more complex though.

Comment: Nice job, but to get the AS3 example you provided to work you must also add:

    import flash.net.navigateToURL;

Thanks,
Larry